# Process.Start creates window with UseShellExecute false and RedirectStandardOutput

Tags: c#, cmd, process.start

So i have the problem, that `Process.Start` always shows a window, even though i have the Properties `CreateNoWindow = true`, `UseShellExecute = false` and `RedirectStandardOuput = true`. On all the tutorial and how to sites, they say that's the way to do it. So what do i miss here?

```
public static void StartExporter(string part, string path)
{
    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    startInfo.Verb = "runas";
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = "/k PartInfoExporter " + part + " " + path;
    var process = Process.Start(startInfo);
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: It probably works, surely you don't actually see cmd's console window.  That "PartInfoExporter.exe" is not supposed to show a window either is something it does not know, you did not tell it that.  And you probably can't tell it that, use a telephone to talk to its programmer.

Comment: I am the programmer of PartInfoExporter and no, this application does not show any window

Comment: What kind of window? The console (cmd)?

Comment: Yes it always shows the cmd window but it shouldn't

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example which does not rely on external components (i.e. `PartInfoExporter`), so that others can try to reproduce it?

Comment: Well, what kind of app is this?  Did you set the project's Output type property to "Windows application" to ensure it never creates a window?  Why are you starting cmd.exe instead of the program you really want to start?  Why are you using /k when you know you can't see anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way cmd.exe works is quite complex (it's actually a VM according to Raymond Chen). Why not skip it, and call PartInfoExporter.exe directly?

Comment: I did it that way now. Thanks.